# How to integrate- $\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{3}}}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{3}}}}dx$$? I am trying to evaluate this integral by substituting $x=(\tan\theta)^{\frac{2}{3}}$. Therefore, $dx=\frac{2}{3}(\cot\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}(\sec^{2}\theta)d\theta$. Therefore, the above integral will become $$\frac{2}{3}\int (\sqrt{(\tan\theta)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\sqrt{(\tan\theta)^{\frac{4}{3}}+|\tan\theta|}})(\cot\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}(\sec^{2}\theta)d\theta$$. Now here $3$ cases will arise. the $1^{st}$ case is $|\tan\theta|=\tan\theta, when(\tan\theta>0)$. The $2^{nd}$ case is $|\tan\theta|=-\tan\theta, when(\tan\theta<0)$. And lastly the $3^{rd}$ case is $|\tan\theta|=0, when(\tan\theta=0)$. But here I am very much confused whether I can take the case of $|\tan\theta|=0, when(\tan\theta)=0$. Because if $\tan\theta=0$, then $\cot\theta=\infty$. Therefore I think the above integral will be undefined in that case. So, please help me out with this question.

Comment: Another simple solution

Answer (score 5):

It would be interesting to consider the infinite series
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{3}}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n}\,x^{\frac{2n+3}{8} }$$
Coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ form respectively sequences $A002596$ and $A046161$ in $OEIS$ and they have a closed form. So, we know all of them and then
$$\int\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{3}}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{8\,a_n}{(2n+11)\,b_n}\,x^{\frac{2n+11}{8} }$$

**Edit**

@JJacquelin having shown  a solution, letting
$$x=\frac{1}{t^4 \left(t^2-2\right)^2}$$ the integrale becomes
$$-8\int \frac{t^2-1}{t^6 \left(t^2-2\right)^4}\,dt$$  Using partial fraction decomposition, the integrand is
$$\frac{1}{2 t^6}+\frac{1}{2 t^4}+\frac{1}{4 t^2}-\frac{1}{4
   \left(t^2-2\right)}+\frac{1}{2
   \left(t^2-2\right)^3}-\frac{1}{\left(t^2-2\right)^4}$$  and the integral is
$$\large\color{blue}{\frac{21 }{256
   \sqrt{2}}\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-t}{\sqrt{2}+t}\right)-}$$
$$\large\color{blue}{\frac{315 t^{10}-1680 t^8+2772 t^6-1152 t^4-256 t^2-1536}{1920_,
   t^5\,\left(t^2-2\right)^3}}$$

Comment: Well done this is much simpler. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{3}}}}dx$$
$$I=\int \sqrt{x+x\sqrt{1+x^{-1/2}}}dx=\int \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x^{-1/2}}}dx$$
$t=x^{-1/2}\quad\implies\quad x=t^{-2}\quad\implies\quad dx=-2t^{-3}dt$
$$I=-2\int t^{-4}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+t}}\:dt$$
Erom WolframAlpha :

[image]

Comment: $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3}}}=\sqrt{x} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}$ is only **True** for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk . $x\geq 0$ because there is $\sqrt{x^3}$ in the function to be integrated.

Comment: Hi Jean ! I made it simpler. Cheers :-)